# Memory management in Qt -- which is proper?

Tags: qt

`PrintIntervalTableModel` implements `QAbstractTableModel`

1) Am I supposed to assign a parent during creation?

```
PrintIntervalTableModel * model = new PrintIntervalTableModel(dataset, this);
ui.table->setModel(model);
```

or

2) Does the `setModel` call set the parent of the model to the view?

```
// Do not pass in a parent widget during construction...
// I have seen this in examples. Is it wrong, right, or a shaky practice?

PrintIntervalTableModel * model = new PrintIntervalTableModel(dataset);
ui.table->setModel(model);
```

If #2 is acceptable or even preferred, how do we know which function calls assign widgets to parents and which don't? It seems dangerous to just assume a call like `setModel` manages child memory if we have no objective evidence that it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what the `void QAbstractItemView::setModel(QAbstractItemModel *model)` says:

The view does not take ownership of the model unless it is the model's parent object because the model may be shared between many different views.

So the view is not the parent of your model using `setModel(...)` function.

When you write `PrintIntervalTableModel * model = new PrintIntervalTableModel(dataset, this);` this refers to the class you are writing your code in, so there's no link with the view (in your example).

To define parent's objet, you can either put `this` in the constructor or call the function `void QObject::setParent(QObject *parent)`, I don't think there is any other way to do it.